# Functions starts as soon as it runs without a call

Tags: javascript, html

Search functions runs as soon as the website opens. I tried removing the  `button.onClick = search();` and that fixes it. I also researched the web and couldn't find anything about button on click code starting function on its own.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#search-input-bar')
const button = document.querySelector('#search-button')

input.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.code === 'Enter') {
        search()
    }
})

function search(){

    let url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + input.value;
    window.open(url);
}

button.onClick = search();
```

```html
        <input id="search-input-bar" type="text">
        <button id="search-button">Search</button>
```

Comment: `search()` is a call to a function that is evaluated as soon as the line of code runs. It should be `button.onclick = search;`

Comment: Why don't you use the `addEventListener()` function like `button.addEventListener('click', search)`? You did that for the keydown event already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is line:

```
button.onClick = search();
```

onClick is an event from React. In regular JS you must write:

```
button.onclick = search();
```

Comment: and that answer has a bug, it will not be invoked with a click.

Comment: `onClick` is a React thing. Regular js and DOM uses `onclick`

Comment: Thank you! I was in a rush and didn't notice that. Fixed the answer